# Prove that if $\gcd(ab,c)=1$, then $\gcd(a,c)=1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

I was told to prove $\gcd(ab,c)=1$ then $\gcd(a,c)=1$.

I picked a number $p$ that goes into $ab$ and $c$, so $ab=px$ and $c=py$. but now what?? I tried $abc=p^2xy$ but then I can't.

Please help me!

Comment: hey , who changed my title?

Comment: You can see the revision history [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/702586/revisions); please note that all-caps titles are strongly discouraged, since all-caps is considered shouting.

Comment: You do now have to write math like this: `$a$$b$=$p$$x$`. You can use `$ab=px$` instead. (You simply end the "math block" enclosed by dollars when you want to start to continue with regular text.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint** $\,\ d\mid a,c\,\Rightarrow\,d\mid ab,c,\,$ but $\,ab,c\,$ are coprime so $\,\ldots$

Comment: wow, thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1):

$\gcd(ab,c)=1 \Leftrightarrow \exists s,t$ such that $(ab)t+cs=1$. But then you have that  $a(bt)+cs=1$ which give you $\gcd(a,c)=1$.

You only use that for $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}$, $\gcd(m,n)=1$ if-f $\exists s,t\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $mt+ns=1$.

Comment: why $gcd(ab,c)=1 $ arrowthingy there exists $ s,t$ such that $(ab)t+cs=1$ ... ?

Comment: Check first theorem here: http://cims.nyu.edu/~kiryl/teaching/aa/les091703.pdf